# Logcat getting empty if any filter option in eclipse is clicked

Tags: android, android-logcat

My logcat is behaving very strange.  If I have started or restarted the eclipse it is showing the logcat values but once I clicked any option For example Allmessages(nofilters) or com.applicationname(sessionfilter) then suddenly logcat is getting empty. I am not able to figure out what is the problem. This problem started once I updated my ADT to 22. Can any one please tell me what is the problem and how to solve this

Thanks

Comment: ok just try this one go to DDMS and then Device then click on your device i hope it will work b=however it worked for me.

Comment: I already tried this trick.

Comment: Yeah, Eclipse gives everyone such nightmares. I get those as well. The only solution I found till now, is to restart the eclipse and hope it works. If you find any concrete approach to solve this, please do share here.

Comment: Yeah you are right, Its nightmare and the only solution I found is same which is restart the eclipse but we can't do all the time. Definitely if I will get solution I will share over here please you do the same to

Answer (score 0):

**1.** If you are using Eclipse, in the DDMS perspective, make sure the correct device (probably emulator-xxxx) is selected and highlighted. Only then will you get the logcat output in the logcat view.

Also, the Android plugin is a bit unstable, and sometimes only shows the last line in the logcat view. If this happens, try to clear the log. After that, you should get all the log entries again.

**2.** However this sometimes happens also, when you have `Mylyn` installed.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1808

**3.** If the LogCat panel is empty in Eclipse the emulator doesn't have the focus. Go to the DDMS perspective and try clicking on the 'emulator' entry in the Devices panel (top-left screen).

Comment: I tries 1, 2 and 3 but nothing worked for me. If I restarting the eclipse then its showing logcat output but again if I clicked any filter its showing nothing

Comment: Well for that you need to define filter for logcat. What are you trying to `filter` based on ? Look at this for more: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html
http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html

Comment: Thanks for your time Dark knight but I know these filters, I am not newbie, Its is not the problem with TAG or pid or by application name

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it usually takes 20 or more seconds for my logcat to display anything. After it does, I see "debugger waiting to settle" messages. This happens every single time.

Try waiting a while to see if it ends up showing up.